# Heroku, cant push my db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I am trying to push my database to heroku, and get this error:

```
Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x89
```

I am using mysql in my local db, and i have coding utf8 in application.rb.
I have try to push with

```
heroku db:push
```

or with

```
heroku db:push mysql2://root:pasword@127.0.0.1/damp?encoding=utf8
```

What can i do to fix this?

Comment: It says PGError - have you purchased and associated a MySQL DB @ heroku?  Their free accounts use PostgreSQL.

Comment: I think that pushed automaticaly to PostgreSQL, because it starting doing schema and sending data. From the error logs, i think that the problem is in specific character in my database

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your database there is a character that needs to be encoded in UTF-8, which isn't currently. I have had this bug in the past and the only solution is to find it out and change it. Painful if you have a large database.

Comment: Ι found the problem, there are binary image in the database. How can i fix this?

Comment: @mike: What is the data type of your image column?

Comment: I just want to ditto the questions 'mu is too short' asked. If the images are stored in the appropriate field type, they shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you mention that you have binary images in your database. The error you're seeing:

> Taps Server Error: PGError: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x89

is coming from some sort of text column, either `varchar` or `text`. In MySQL you want one of the [BLOB types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/blob.html), in PostgreSQL you want a [`BYTEA` column](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html), and in with ActiveRecord you want the [`binary` column type](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#supported-types). Your table definition should look something like this:

```
create_table :your_table do |t|
    #...
    t.binary :image_column_name
    #...
end
```